# My form fields are no longer coming though on the update page?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a model 'Partner' with a one-to-many relationship to 'Product'. When I added the 'Product' formset I broke something to do with the relationships - the html still shows up eg `<h3>Products</h3>`, and the submit button remains but there are no longer any of the form boxes. So it looks like the form is being loaded but something isn't being passed anymore maybe. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code below.

my forms.py

```
<div class="container">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
    <h1>Preview</h1>
    <hr/>
        <div class='content-preview'>
            <h3 id='preview-name'></h3>
            <p id='preview-mission'></p>
            <p id='preview-vision'></p>
            <p id='preview-website-link'></p>
            <p id='preview-fb-link'></p>
            <p id='preview-twitter-link'></p>
            <p id='preview-ig-link'></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <h1>Form</h1>
        <hr/>
        <form method='POST' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>{% csrf_token %}
            {{ partnerForm|crispy }}
            {{ formset.management_form }}
            <br>
            <h3>Products</h3>
            {% for form in formset %}
                {{ form|crispy }}
            {% endfor %}
            <input type='submit' class='btn btn-default' value='Create Partner' />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

my form.html

```
class PartnerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    mission = forms.CharField(widget=PagedownWidget(show_preview=False))
    vision = forms.CharField(widget=PagedownWidget(show_preview=False))
    # publish = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget)
    class Meta:
        model = Partner
        fields = [
            "name",
            "logo",
            "banner_image",
            "mission",
            "vision",
            "website_link",
            "store_link",
            "fb_link",
            "twitter_link",
            "ig_link",
        ]

class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image = forms.ImageField(label='Image')
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            "name",
            "link",
            "description",
            "price",
            "image",
        ]
```

my views.py

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect

##
from django.forms import modelformset_factory
from django.template import RequestContext

# Create your views here.
from .forms import PartnerForm, ProductForm
from .models import Partner, Product
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory


def partner_create(request):

    if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
        raise Http404

    ProductFormSet = modelformset_factory(Product, form=ProductForm, extra=2, min_num=1)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        partnerForm = PartnerForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        formset = ProductFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, queryset=Product.objects.none())

        if partnerForm.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            print(formset.cleaned_data)

            instance = partnerForm.save(commit=False)
            instance.save()

            products = formset.save(commit=False)
            for product in products:
                product.partner = instance
                product.save()

            messages.success(request, "Partner Successfully Created")
        else:
            print partnerForm.errors, formset.errors
    else:
        partnerForm = PartnerForm()
        formset = ProductFormSet(queryset=Product.objects.none())
    return render(request, "partner_form.html", {"partnerForm": partnerForm, "formset": formset})



def partner_detail(request, slug=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Partner, slug=slug)
    context = {
        "name": instance.name,
        "instance": instance
    }
    return render(request, "partner_detail.html", context)

def partner_list(request):
    queryset = Partner.objects.all()
    context = {
        "partner_list": queryset,
        "name": "List"
    }
    return render(request, "partner_list.html", context)

def partner_update(request, slug=None):
    if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
        raise Http404
    instance = get_object_or_404(Partner, slug=slug)
    partnerForm = PartnerForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=instance)

    if partnerForm.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        messages.success(request, "Partner Saved")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())

    context = {
        "name": instance.name,
        "instance": instance,
        "form": partnerForm
    }
    return render(request, "partner_form.html", context)
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Update</h1>")
```

Please let me know if there is anything else I can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `partner_create` and `partner_update` views both render the  `partner_form.html` template.

However you do not include `partnerForm` or `formset` in the context in the `partner_update` view. Instead you include `form`, which you do not use anywhere in the template.